# free component for diagram/chart/graph in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I would like to ask what is the free component for diagram/chart/graph in Vaadin 14?

I am using Vaadin14 and Spring boot in my project,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Available third party add-ons shared by users can be found at the [Vaadin directory](https://vaadin.com/directory/). You should search if there is any that suits you :)

I have never tried this add-on, but it seems to be widely used and actively maintained : [ApexCharts.js](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/apexchartsjs)

Answer (score 0):

[**SO Charts**](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/so-charts/overview) - this add-on is a wrapper around the [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/) Javascript library for using it with Vaadin Flow.